# What is the "debian-+" user?

Tags: linux, debian, process, users, top

While watching `top` some process flashed before my eyes with strange `USER`-column `debian-+`.

I checked that this particular process belongs to *`/usr/bin/tor`*.
But I can't see the user `debian-+` in Linux files like e.g. *`/etc/passwd`*. There is only `debian-tor` user there.

So what is the need for user `debian-+`? Is it only related to *tor* or something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s the `debian-tor` user, but `top` truncates it to `debian-+` (the `+` indicates that the value was truncated).

The default width for the `USER` column is 8 characters, and the column doesn’t scale with its contents. The width can be adjusted with <kbd>X</kbd> while `top` is running.

Answer (score 1):

Expand the output for username in `ps`, there you can see the full name:

```
ps ax o user:16,pid,pcpu,pmem,vsz,rss,stat,start_time,time,cmd
```